# Is there a way to host the logs of tomcat (catalina, error) logs of one server into another server?

Tags: apache, logging, tomcat7, tomcat8, catalina

I've hosted few Rest APIs on my tomcat server. The logs generated are huge and causing frequent throttling of server. I just want to move these logs to another server automatically. Is there any way to do that? The logs on the main server should be deleted once they are moved to log server.

Answer (score 0):

for handling and customizing logging activities you can use Log4j with tomcat . It have log4j.properties file in which user can customizing size of log which he or she want to archive . for more details you can refer following link:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html
Aso if you want to transfer your logs to another server better approach to use NFS server.
Using NFS server you can handle the large size of data transfer to mount point on NFS server.